# Is it possible to edit the numbers displayed on an axis without moving the points that were plotted?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I've come up with a graph (a scatterplot) of the `log(1+inf)` (inf = number of people infected with a given disease on the y-axis against one of the explanatory variables, in this case, the populational density (pop./km²; x-axis) on my model. The log transformation was used merely for visualization, because it spreads the distribution of the data and allows for more aesthetically appealing plots. Basically, what I want is both axis to show the value of that same variable before the log transformation. The dots need to be plotted like `plot(log(1+inf),log(populational_density)`, but the number on the axis should refer to `plot(inf,populational_density)`. I've provided a picture of my graph with some manual editing on the y-axis to show you the idea of what I want.

[image: example]

- The numbers in red would be the 'inf' values equivalent to log(inf);

**Please, bear in mind that those values in red do not correspond to reality.**

I understand the whole concept of y = f(x), but i've been asked to provide it. Is this possible? I'm using the `ggplot2`package for plotting.

Comment: I think I would need a visual example to understand what you want

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for examples of how to do it.

Comment: @SamPer I've added a graph and further exaplanation of what I want. Please let me know if it's easier to understand now.

Comment: @Z.Lin , I'm afraid I can't give a reproducible example because I'm not discussing any particular errors, I'm talking about functionalities of a plot package on R. I need the data to be plotted using transformed variables but I need the axis to show untransformed values, and I can't give you an example because I don't know how to do this which I'm asking here. If I misunderstood you, please specify what you mean by "example" and I'll gladly provide it. I also inserted a graph on the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @EricLino The point of a reproducible example is not (in this case) about reproducing errors. It's meant to give everyone a common context to work on. It's often frustrating for pple to write up a solution to a broadly described problem, only for the poster to say their actual requirements are different in some way. You've included a graph here; you can post the code used to generate it. (If the real dataset is not commonly available, generate a fake one is also fine.)